# Converting adjacency matrix into table with from/to/frequency

Tags: r, igraph, sna

I have a situation like this one:

| id | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| b | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| c | 0 | 11 | 2 |

The observations are frequencies of how many times a contacts b, ecc...

I need a dataframe like this one:

| from | to | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b |  |
| a | c |  |
| a | a |  |
| b | a |  |
| b | c |  |
| b | b |  |
| c | a |  |
| c | b |  |
| c | c |  |

Comment: `library(data.table); melt(setDT(df),"id")`